# Call data from another form in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to call the data that is in another form, is this possible? I publish a summary code. I use this is Java + JSF + Primefaces When I look for the values ​​of tramiteBean.description, I get null. Thank you

```
 <p:tabView id="tab">
    <p:tab title="Title1">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:textEditor value="#{tramiteBean.descripcion}"  id="descripcion"/>    
            <p:inputNumber value="#{tramiteBean.idTipo}"  id="tipo"/>   
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Title2">
        <h:form id="form2">
            <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{control.doSome}" update=":tab:form1"/> 
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible.
Taking input from one form and submiting another form works.
Why don't you wrap the entire tabView in a single form?

```
<h:form>
<p:tabView id="tab">
<p:tab title="Title1">
<p:textEditor value="#{tramiteBean.descripcion}"  id="descripcion"/>    
        <p:inputNumber value="#{tramiteBean.idTipo}"  id="tipo"/> 
</p:tab>


<p:tab title="Title2">
<p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{control.doSome}" update=":tab:form1"/> 
</p:tab>

</p:tabView>

</h:form>
```

Comment: I want to do it because I have other buttons in the tabs and I want to divide the solution, but if you say that it is not possible I will believe you, because I have not found any solution either

Comment: @Jose, why don't you try putting forms inside tab and the action buttons inside the respective tabs?

Comment: please cand you publish the example? thanks.

Comment: [link](https://notepad.pw/multiTabForm)
Here you go.
Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helps. That would be very helful

Comment: but it doesn't work without the updates

Comment: what updates? I have not included any update in my demo sample

Comment: i said the example need update=form ....

Comment: Yes, just give update="formName", it will work as expected. Just play around a little bit. You'll reach where you need to.